# MSBuild: Treat single warning as error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, msbuild

**Is there a way to force MSBuild to treat a certain warning as an error?**

When running the Publish target for a ccproj file to make a cspkg for deployment to Azure, this error is thrown:

> Project.Name : warning WAT150: The project 'Project.Name' is
>   dependent on the following assembly:
>   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\DllName\2.10.0.0__Guid\DllName.dll. This
>   assembly is not in the package. To make sure that the role starts, add
>   this assembly as a reference to the project and set the Copy Local
>   property to true.
>   [C:\bld\66\797\Sources\Applications\cloud\Project.Name.ccproj]

This is a warning that probably means a role won't start when deployed... I'd like to make WAT150 an error.  **Is there a way to make a specific, single warning or list of warnings an error?**

Answer (score 6):

In MSBuild you can use the `/warnaserror` command line switch

```
  /warnaserror[:code[;code2]]
                     List of warning codes to treats as errors.  Use a semicolon
                     or a comma to separate multiple warning codes. To treat all
                     warnings as errors use the switch with no values.
                     (Short form: /err[:c;[c2]])

                     Example:
                       /warnaserror:MSB4130

                     When a warning is treated as an error the target will
                     continue to execute as if it was a warning but the overall
                     build will fail.
```

This is equivalent to setting the `<WarningsAsErrors>` property in the project file ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019)).

For completeness, the C# compiler also has the `-warnaserror` command line option ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/warnaserror-compiler-option)).

Answer (score 3):

in the msbuild commandline options you have this:

warningsAsErrors

Specifies a list of warnings to treat as errors. This parameter is equivalent to the /warnaserror compiler switch.

doc link : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb629394(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb629394%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This is actually not a **command line** option. The command-line option would be `/p:key=value`, with the **key** being `warningsAsErrors`

Comment: and `value` being `true`