# Force msbuild to fail on specific warning

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I would like MSBuild to fail on the specific warning MSB3274 (which is what you get when a reference cannot be resolved because it was built against a higher version than the currently targeted framework).

I tried

```
MSBuild.exe .\test.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU /p:WarningsAsErrors=MSB3274
```

but the warning is still treated as a warning, and the build succeeds.

How can I get an error from MSBuild if the build produces this specific warning?

**About the "question already has answer" note**: the answer to the question "[MSBuild: Treat single warning as error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552055/msbuild-treat-single-warning-as-error)" **does not** work in this case, as I stated in the example where I'm already using the `WarningsAsErrors` property.

Comment: Same idea, different warning: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17495278/128384

Comment: @stijn: interesting solution, thansk. How strange that there's no msbuild command line parameter though.

Comment: @HansPassant: TreatWarningsAsErrors should treat *all* warnings as errors, here I just wanted a specific one. However, if I specify it, the build succeeds anyway.